# ParSeq.fill running sequentially?

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, scala-collections

I am trying to initialize an array in Scala, using parallelization. However, when using `ParSeq.fill` method, the performance doesn't seem to be better any better than sequential initialization (`Seq.fill`). If I do the same task, but initializing the collection with `map`, then it is much faster.

To show my point, I set up the following example:

```
import scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParSeq
import scala.util.Random

object Timer {
  def apply[A](f: => A): (A, Long) = {
    val s = System.nanoTime
    val ret = f
    (ret, System.nanoTime - s)
  }
}

object ParallelBenchmark extends App {

  def randomIsPrime: Boolean = {
    val n = Random.nextInt(1000000)
    (2 until n).exists(i => n % i == 0)
  }

  val seqSize = 100000

  val (_, timeSeq) = Timer { Seq.fill(seqSize)(randomIsPrime) }
  println(f"Time Seq:\t\t $timeSeq")
  val (_, timeParFill) = Timer { ParSeq.fill(seqSize)(randomIsPrime) }
  println(f"Time Par Fill:\t $timeParFill")
  val (_, timeParMap) = Timer { (0 until seqSize).par.map(_ => randomIsPrime) }
  println(f"Time Par map:\t $timeParMap")

}
```

And the result is:

```
Time Seq:        32389215709
Time Par Fill:   32730035599
Time Par map:    17270448112
```

Clearly showing that the fill method is not running in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parallel collections library in Scala can only parallelize existing collections, `fill` hasn't been implemented yet (and may never be). Your method of using a `Range` to generate a cheap placeholder collection is probably your best option if you want to see a speed boost.

Here's the underlying method being called by [`ParSeq.fill`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/70f0b1ded8/src%2Flibrary%2Fscala%2Fcollection%2Fgeneric%2FGenTraversableFactory.scala#L85-L94), obviously not parallel.